# Update Api from Ajax to Python

Tags: python, ajax, rest, api, flask

I don't know how to append data to API in Flask from JS to Python without using a global list in Python route, which is causing all users to see same API info.

I have an ajax post request in my JS static file that allows a user to select an item and upon selecting that item it posts that data to Python route which then loads data and appends it to a global array. And then within the route I return the JSON list to the api. I am trying to figure out another way to do this because with this method first of all from my understanding global variables are God awful for this exact reason because all users can see the global api info.

```
// On load cart
window.onload = function wowzers(){
  var array = [];
  var sum = 0;
  // Get Data
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'pricing/orders/' + username +'/api', true);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400){
      for(x in data){
        for(key in data[x]){
          array.push(Number(data[x][key]));
          sum+=Number(data[x][key]);
          subtotal.innerHTML = sum;
          row = cart.insertRow(-1);
          // Delete Data
          row.addEventListener('click', function deleterow(){
            index = this.rowIndex;
            $.post('pricing/orders/delete', {
              delete_item: index
            });
             cart.deleteRow(index);
             subtotal.innerHTML = sum-Number(cart.rows[index].cells[1].innerHTML);
          });
          cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          cell1.innerHTML = key;
          cell2. innerHTML = data[x][key];
          cell3. innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>"
        }
      }
      console.log(sum);
    }else{
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  xhr.send()
}

//Dynamic Cart
for(x = 0; x < tablerows; x++){
  table.rows[x].addEventListener('click', addCartItem);
}
function addCartItem(ev){
  var array = [];
  var sum = 0;
  index = this.rowIndex;
  equipmentCell = table.rows[index].cells[0];
  priceCell = table.rows[index].cells[1];
  equipmentName = equipmentCell.innerHTML;
  equipmentPrice = priceCell.innerHTML;
  // Post Data
  $.post('/pricing/orders/' + username + '/api', {
    javascript_data: JSON.stringify({[equipmentName]:equipmentPrice})
  });
  cartrow = cart.insertRow(-1);

  // Delete Data
  cartrow.addEventListener('click', function deleterow(){
    index = this.rowIndex;
    subtotal.innerHTML = sum-Number(cart.rows[index].cells[1].innerHTML);
    $.post('pricing/orders/delete', {
      delete_item: index
    });
    cart.deleteRow(index);
  });
  cell1 = cartrow.insertCell(0);
  cell2 = cartrow.insertCell(1);
  cell3 = cartrow.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML= equipmentName;
  cell2.innerHTML = equipmentPrice;
  cell3.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>";
  // Open Api information
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'pricing/orders/' + username +'/api', true);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400){
      for(x in data){  
        for(y in data[x]){
          array.push(Number(data[x][y]));
          sum+=Number(data[x][y]);
          subtotal.innerHTML = sum;
        }
      }
    }else{
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

**Route Logic**

```
# ---------------------------------- USER CART API -----------------------------
@app.route('/pricing/orders/<user_name>/api', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def api(user_name):
    user_name = current_user.username
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart.append(json.loads(request.form["javascript_data"]))
    return jsonify(cart)

# ---------------------------- DELETE ITEM IN CART ROUTE ----------------------------------
@app.route('/pricing/orders/delete', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def delete_item():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(cart[json.loads(request.form["delete_item"])])
        cart.pop(json.loads(request.form["delete_item"]))
        print(cart)
    return jsonify({"whoa": "there"})

# ----------------------------- DISPLAY CART BADGE LENGTH---------------------------------
@app.context_processor
def inject_badge_length():
    badge_length = len(cart)
    return {'BADGE_LENGTH' : badge_length}
```

I'm hoping I can post data to Python route and then append particular data to API without global list so all users are only able to view their own data. I'm a beginner in the RESTFUL API arena, and just need pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are running into an issue with [storing data](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/storing.html).

Most likely, you will want some type of ORM like [SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/) to handle your data storage. It has a bit of a learning curve, but will make things much easier to manage in the long run.

Comment: Hey thanks I am using SQLAlchemy but I don’t want to store the data to the db just yet until I’ve confirmed the orders in the cart and have made the purchase. I was steered in the direction of using a restful api which I was told would be the best for this issue, considering I would be eliminating refreshes of the whole web page, and save only the data I need to the db.

Comment: I see, in that case you may want to store the information as a cookie for the user, and then send it to the DB when it is confirmed?

Comment: Cool, like I said in the post I’m quite a noob could you possibly point me in the right direction of doing this, and would the data within the cookie be mutable, allowing for me to delete elements within cookie and appending as well without using a global variable? This is simulating a shopping cart so items can be deleted.

Comment: In that case, I honestly would store that data in your database under a different section specifically for "In-Cart" objects. This will give you a lot more freedom to add and delete items, along with keeping the cart stored over different sessions.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but then again this would cause for the web page to refresh on adding each item and deleting each item in the cart which would diminish the user’s overall experience even though it may be easier to work with programmatically wise.

Comment: If you are using AJAX you should be able to make API requests without having to refresh the page. From the Wikipedia: "With Ajax, web applications can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)